# How to display template literals inside template literal in HTML children property?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to do some code formatting and display code snippets in my page. I'm using react-highlight.js to do this. Code and working example as below:

https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-morning-v4ew3?file=/src/index.js

Now what I want to put in between the backticks are:

```
componentDidMount() {
    document.title = `You clicked ${this.state.count} times`
}
componentDidUpdate() {
    document.title = `You clicked ${this.state.count} times`
}
```

However the template literal in the above code is causing problems as below:
[image]

Can someone tell me how I can put the above code in the code snippet?

EDIT: the lifecycle methods do no do anything. They should simply be formatted and displayed in the code snippet generated.

Comment: Please define "causing trouble" Edit: Also, you seem to be using functional components, which don't have the `componentDidMount`/`componentDidUpdate` lifecycle methods.

Comment: @DBS the lifecycle method are the code snippets I'm trying to display, it does not matter what code being displayed inside the backticks

Comment: As you are using functional components, you should use hooks instead of those methods, specifically the [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) hook (The example they give in the documentation is almost exactly what you are trying to do)

Comment: @DBS the lifecycle methods in the code does NOT do anything, they should only be displayed, I was trying to display some code in my page, like what you put between ``` ``` in StackOverflow

Comment: So this question is about displaying text with code formatting? If that's the case I'm afraid you need to make some significant edits to the question to make it clearer.

Comment: @DBS Can you suggest how I should edit my question? I thought the code example is self-explanary.

Comment: one quick solution will be, pass base64 encoded string value using `btoa` or any other of your choice
& decode it in child component.

issue is improper use of `\`` tilted quote.
use \ before inner `\``

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape the special characters inside your template literal:

Before each back tick or dollar sign, add a back slash `\`

```
code = {`componentDidMount() {
    document.title = \`You clicked \${this.state.count} times\`
}
componentDidUpdate() {
    document.title = \`You clicked \${this.state.count} times\`
}`}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can escape it with a backslash.

```
<CodeBlock
    code={
       `componentDidMount() {
           document.title = \`You clicked \${this.state.count} times\`
       }
       componentDidUpdate() {
          document.title = \`You clicked \${this.state.count} times\`
       }`
    }
 />
```

[Here](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/05/es6-in-depth-template-strings-2/) you will find a great article about template strings if you need more information.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like whats causing the trouble is the back-tick openers and the ${this.state...} variable

ive done some changes and just assigned the {this.state.counter} to a variable

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import Highlight from "react-highlight";

const CodeBlock = (props) => {

  return (
    <div>
      <Highlight language="javascript">
        <div children={props.code} />
      </Highlight>
    </div>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  let state = "${this.state.count}"
  return (
    <CodeBlock
      code={`componentDidMount() {
        document.title = "You clicked ${state} times"
      }
      componentDidUpdate() {
        document.title = "You clicked ${state} times"
  }`}
    />
  );
};

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

hope that helps ;)